# Export to multiple sheets in Excel file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, export, apache-poi, primefaces-extensions

I want to export multiple data tables, each in a separate sheet, in one Excel file using primefaces 4.0 or primefaces extension exporter. Can this be done?

Comment: get all the data and use Apache poi to create all sheets in one file, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jxl](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) framework for Excel file handling. I think it is still one of the best options.

An example:

```
public void createExcelReport(OutputStream stream) {
        WritableWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            Workbook template = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(getClass().getResource("/report/report_template.xls").getFile()));
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(stream, template);
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
            int idx = START_ROW_IDX;
            for (SomePojo pojo : pojoService.getPojos()) {
                writePojoToRow(pojo);       
                        idx++;
            }
            if (idx == START_ROW_IDX) {
                addNoErrorSheet(sheet);
            }
            workbook.write();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("There was a problem here.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Excel file creation did not work because of this Exception: ", e);
        } finally {
            if (workbook != null) {
                try {
                    workbook.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like to use primefaces or apache-poi only if possible since this page is a part of a bigger project. Thanks for the suggestion though.